# iOS capturePhoto() not taking highest resolution photos only on iPad 11" 3rd gen front camera

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avcapturedevice

The goal is to take the highest resolution photo the camera is capable of.

The camera selected is the iPad 11" 3rd gen (w/M1) front camera: the new 12MP TrueDepth camera.
Although this code **does** take the highest resolution photos on iPhone 12 mini and all other device i've tested, it does **not** on the iPad 11" 3rd gen: instead of taking a 12MP photo, the photo comes back as 7MP (3088x2316).

Can anyone spot what i'm doing wrong? The only code i've omitted that i'm aware might matter is the fact that i'm turning on meta info + depth delivery too (adding a `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` and `AVCaptureDepthDataOutput` as well as the usual `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`). Frustratingly I don't have an iPad 11" 3rd gen available to test, I'm relying on users who are helping me debug this problem.

Many thanks for any help!

```
    self.session = AVCaptureSession.init()
    self.session.sessionPreset = .photo
    ...
    self.photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput.init()
    self.photoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true
    self.photoOutput.isLivePhotoCaptureEnabled = false
    self.photoOutput.maxPhotoQualityPrioritization = .quality
    ...
    let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg, AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: [AVVideoQualityKey: 0.8]])
    photoSettings.photoQualityPrioritization = .quality
    photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
    photoSettings.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true
    photoSettings.isPortraitEffectsMatteDeliveryEnabled = true
    ... capturePhoto...
```

Comment: I can test iPad Pro 12.9" 3rd gen, if that works

Comment: thanks aheze! that one has a 7MP front and those pics seem to be working at the moment, but after i make changes i'll ask you!

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer from a kind senior Apple engineer. It's not what I expected!

Short version: the camera sensor is 12MP, but it takes photos at 7MP because the center part that's geometrically correct is 7MP.... the outsides of the sensor are fish-eyed for FaceTime Center Stage, which you can see if you zoom out on widest angle view. The Camera App upscales the 7MP photo 12MP but it's actually 7MP of detail.